# MySQL Query assistance apply filtering to two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello I am not sure how to do this query looking for some guidance...

The output should be a column with a single row 'Total Sales for 2004' and
another column with a single row 'Total Sales for 2005'.

using classicmodels.orders (orderNumber, OrderDate)
and classicmodels.orderdetails(orderNumber,PriceEach)

How would you be able to apply filtering clauses to two different columns?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please show us your effort and ask about specific problem you are having.

Comment: What language are you using? The quick version: `SELECT "Total Sales for 2004" AS SALES UNION ALL SELECT "Total Sales for 2005"`  you only wanted one column right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 2004 THEN od.PriceEach ELSE 0 END) Total_Sales_for_2004,
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(o.OrderDate) = 2005 THEN od.PriceEach ELSE 0 END) Total_Sales_for_2005
FROM 
    orders o
    INNER JOIN orderdetails od ON od.orderNumber = o.orderNumber
WHERE YEAR(o.OrderDate) IN (2004, 20O5)
```

Comment: Yes exactly what I was looking for I was thinking some kind of pivot table but I couldn't add an additional filtered column.  Thanks!